# Our Website is being blocked in critical areas - how do I get to the bottom of this?

Tags: security, networking

I'm working with a UK-based contractor in the counter-terrorism industry. I've noticed that when I'm in Virginia Beach (near Norfolk and Washington DC), I cannot get a connection to the website through the wireless network (WiFi), either on my phone or on my laptop.

If I do a `tracert` from a PC hooked up to the local network, I get a bunch of `"*        *        *     Request timed out."` lines. I can access the website from my phone using 3G in the parking lot.

What diagnostics can I do that will reveal what is going on?

Comment: A traceroute will tell you where problems are occurring.

Comment: If your ISP is using filtered DNS, check to see if the website has been included in the "Known terrorist discussion websites" blocklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website is likely blocked by a proxy filter being used on your local and wireless network like this [one](http://www.websense.com/content/web-filter-features.aspx) (possibly due to its relevancy to "terrorism" and proximity to Washington D.C.). You can check if various categories are being blocked by clicking on links [here](http://testdatabasewebsense.com/Default.aspx).

To find out more specific information, you should contact the admin of your local and wireless network, or the ISP providing your network's connection to the Internet, to ask if they can provide any details as to why it's being blocked. If you don't know who your ISP is, you can do an IP address lookup with an online tool like this [one](http://network-tools.com/) which should display your IP address automatically (select "Network Lookup" and look for an "admin" or "tech" contact field).

Performing a [trace route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) on the same network in which you're being blocked isn't going to reveal much information. Doing so from online sites however might. To see if your website is also being blocked for others outside your network, you could perform trace routes using various online sites like this [one](http://visualroute.visualware.com/) (select the "route" test), which would allow you to chose different locations/networks to originate the trace route from.

This would allow you to see if any network nodes are timing out. You can then look up the admin for the IP address of that network node (by clicking on the "Table" tab and then the link under "Network Name") and contact them as well (by phone is typically faster than email).